# Setup dual monitor for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have an old desktop monitor which is not used now.
How can I setup dual monitor with my Laptop?

My laptop specification:

- LG R700 17'
- OS : Windows 7 RC
- Graphic : GeForce 8600M GS
- VGA analog (no DVI port)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should need to do is plug it in.  Windows should ask you if you want to mirror the desktop or extend the desktop.  Select extend the desktop.

Comment: If it does nothing, you can still try to trigger that dialog manually by pressing Windows+P.